# Partial cramping in VM after squats

Tags: cramps

I've experienced this twice now. A few hours after my workout, I'll be lounging around (with my leg bent) and suddenly get a slight burn in my VM ("the  teardrop"). If I straighten my leg, the burn intensifies.

Is this a sign I *really do* need to start stretching post-workout or do I just need more potassium?

I'm doing Strong Lifts, so my legs *are* getting worked pretty hard.

Comment: How intense is your squats program? With dumbbells, barbell, or machine?

Comment: @Kneel, see edit.

Comment: Based on the information given *(Stronglifts requires you to have low, warmup sets so that your muscles are adapted to the weights),* I highly doubt that the cramp is caused by the squats. I would suggest you pay more attention to other activities performed after the exercises. And yes, you likely need more potassium :). Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

Even with the measures you've indicated, there's no guarantee that the cramps will stop.  Cramping is not well understood.  It's not simply caused by low potassium, sodium, or electrolytes.  Those may certainly affect cramping, but, there are other factors involved, some of which, are not fully understood.  Age, prior injury, and, recovery ability can certainly play a role in the severity and frequency of cramps.  You should try to record the circumstances that may have resulted in your cramping (even if only making a mental note) when it occurs.  Later, if you have another episode you can refer to your notes to try and figure it out.  I've been troubled by calf cramps in only **one** leg.  I've started to build some anecdotal evidence that it may have something to do with consuming *caffeine* before a training session.  Stretching has helped, but, they persist with no rhyme or reason that I can tell as yet.